# Obtener arreglos individuales en con PDO fetchAll

Tags: php

buen dia, estoy intentando hacer algunas validaciones con fetch all

este es mi codigo

```
    $usuariodb = strtolower($_POST['usuario']);
    $passworddb = strtolower($_POST['password']);

    $conn = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=db;charset=UTF8','guest','guest');
    //$sql = "SELECT name FROM loginUsr WHERE name ='".strtolower($usuariodb)."'";
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM loginUsr BETWEEN name = $usuariodb AND password = $passworddb";
    $result = $conn->query($sql);
    //nombre del usuario en db para validar
    $rows = $result->fetchAll();


    if ($usuariodb == $rows['name']) {
        header('Location: prueba.php');
    }
```

la ultima parte del if me gustaria acceder directamente a cada una de los datos de las filas directamente pero estoy consiguiendo como salida 
Fatal error: Call to a member function fetchAll()

Answer (score 1):

Creo que te falta indicar el tipo de fetchAll.

Prueba de este modo

```
$rows = $result->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

Comment: Ese no es el error... [leer más sobre los parámetros fetch](http://php.net/manual/es/pdostatement.fetch.php/#refsect1-pdostatement.fetch-parameters)

Comment: no me funciona.

Answer (score 1):

El método fetch solo regresa un PDOStatement si el query es correcto, en caso contrario regresa false y por eso te da el error.